# changing sharepoint 2010 main page URL

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Dears, I want to change my share point (which is installed on windows server 2008 and is an internal site) main page URL to a new one.

now this is something like http://servername/SitePages/Home.aspx
but I want to change server name to a better name like :
OurSharePoint.com

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an alternate access mapping for an internal URL to be whatever you like.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208(office.12).aspx